# Angular 8 +Spring Boot + Tomcat: Error 404

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, tomcat

Tengo una aplicacion utilizando Spring Boot con Angular, ejecuto mi proyecto Java desde mi IDE Eclipse y no aparece ningun problema de igual manera mi proyecto Angular, en mi explorador me arranca bien la aplicacion y me muestra los registros de mi base de datos.

El problema aqui es cuando genero el artefacto .war de mi proyecto Java Spring boot y lo subo a mi Tomcat, al parecer no sale ningun error al deployarlo, pero cuando abro mi aplicacion en algun explorador no me aparecen los registros y me sale un error 404.

version Tomcat: 9.0.1

Spring boot: 2.1.6

comparto pedasos de codigo.

Imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

clase main de proyecto Spring boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan 
public class EjemploSpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{ //se agrega extends SpringBootServletInitializer


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(EjemploSpringBootApplication.class, args);
  }

  //metodo agregado
  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(EjemploSpringBootApplication.class);
  }


  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
      return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
          @Override
          public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

  registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST","PUT", "DELETE");
          }
      };
  }
}
```

Por lo leido en otros foros y paginas en la clase Main se debe extender a extends SpringBootServletInitializer{.....   y agregar el metodo de configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application){} que tengo para cuando genere el artefacto con maven y lo deploye en Tomcat no salga algun error 404.

Genero mi .war con: mvn clean package

Dependencias del pom.xml:

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

En el proyecto Java tengo una clase Controller y hago un pequeño ejemplo para mostra un mensaje pero ni ese me muestra,

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4401")//conexion de URL al proyecto Angular
@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeController {   

   private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(EmployeeController.class);

 //Introdusco la URL http://localhost:8080/EjemploSpringBoot-0.0.1/api/controller para mostrar el mensaje para hacer prueba. 
 @GetMapping("/controller")
    public String hello() {
       return "MENSAJE 1111111111";
    }

@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

@GetMapping("/employees")
public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() throws IOException {    
    log.debug("Obtiene todos los empleados ----->");
    try {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION:" + e);
        log.error("ERROR: "+e);
        return (List<Employee>) e;
    }
}
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

El recurso http://localhost:8080/api/employes al que accedes no existe en el servidor o no esta levantado. Y es obvio no?? Le pusiste localhost a la url. Eso tal vez exista en tu maquina donde lo desarrollaste, no el el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Debes de ingresar el nombre de tu API o si no se tiene la definición del path en el archivo properties de spring boot debes de tomar el nombre de tu proyecto, justo como indica en la siguiente linea..

```
//Introdusco la URL http://localhost:8080/EjemploSpringBoot-0.0.1/api/controller para mostrar el mensaje para hacer prueba.
```

Esto también aplica a todos los recursos, es decir ...

```
http://localhost:8080/EjemploSpringBoot-0.0.1/api/employees
```

Suerte...

Answer (score 0):

Te falta el contextpath de tu aplicacion, esto se define por lo general en el build.gradle server.servlet.context-path= o en caso que no encuentre esta propiedad tomara el nombre de tu aplicacion como contextPath

Por ejemplo tu proyecto se llama luis-soriano y tienes un endpoint

```
@GettingMapping("/api/hello")
```

deberias llamar el endpoint de esta manera (angular)
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/luis-soriano/api/hello')

Ahora:

- 404 -> el endpoint que estas llamando no existe porque no hay ningun
  servicio desplegado con path http://localhost:8080/api/lo-que-sea
- Cors -> no tiene nada que ver con un 404 esto te sirve cuando quieres
  llamar un endpoint desde un origen distinto de donde esta deplegada
  tu app por ej.:

> tu app se encuentra en http://luis-sorano:8080/my-app pero tu la
> llamas desde http://localhost:4200/my-app // tu javascript esta en un
> server local con puerto 4200 por lo general, no se permiten este tipo
> de llamadas por que es vulnerable a un ataque de cross site domain
> http://www.securityandit.com/security/understanding-cross-domain-attack/
> a menos que lo fuerces

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot recientemente necesita que le habiliten permisos para que la api pueda ser consumida, eso forma parte de la seguridad de spring en la clase controlador se necesita darle permisos a este caso a angular y angular la url del servidor por defecto es localhost:4200, y le habilitamos el permiso asi

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
```

en la clase del controllador.